# boundary of a 3-cell

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

> Let $I^k=\underbrace{[0,1]\times [0,1]\times \cdots \times [0,1]}_{k \ \mbox{times}}$. Calculate $\partial (I^3)$ (the boundary of $I^3$) rigorously.

I can realize that it has to be the six surfaces of cubes.

For example in case of $I^2$. I could realize that $\partial(I^2)=\partial\sigma_1+\partial\sigma_2$, where $\sigma_1=[0,e_1,e_2]$ and $\sigma_2=[e_1+e_2,e_2,e_1]$.

[image]

In case of $I^3$, I want to find $\sigma_i$'s such that
$$I^3=\sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i$$

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you asking?

Comment: I think I have clearly stated that I want to calculate $\partial (I^3)$ rigorously. @Robin

Comment: Yes, but then you indicate that you don't understand how to realize the orientations. This is separate from rigor, as you could just apply the formula as [found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Algebraic_topology) and that would be a rigorous calculation.

Comment: May be I was not clear. I am having trouble in separating the boundary of $I^3$. $\partial (I^3) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \partial \sigma_i$. I can see one of them say $\sigma_1$ has to be $[0,e_1,e_2,e_3]$. But I am not sure whether $\sigma_2$ (say) is $[e_1+e_2,e_1,e_2,e_1+e_2+e_3]$ or $[e_1+e_2,e_2,e_1,e_1+e_2+e_3]$. I know that it has to be a permutation of those four points.

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow see my above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I find the answer from Rudin. It says
$$I^3=\sum\sigma^{(i_1,i_2,i_3)}$$
where the sum runs over all possible permutations $(i_1,i_2,i_3)$ of $(1,2,3)$ and where
$$\sigma^{(i_!,i_2,i_3)}=s(i_1,i_2,i_3)[0,e_{i_1},e_{i_1}+e_{i_2},e_{i_1}+e_{i_2}+e_{i_3}]$$
$s(i_1,i_2,i_3)$ is the sign of the permutation $(i_1,i_2,i_3)$.

Anyway new answers are still welcome.